# Sum of all possible values of $\gcd(a-1,a^2+a+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the sum of all possible values of
>   $$\gcd(a-1,a^2+a+1)$$
>   where $a$ is a positive integer.

Comment: The raw question, without showing personal effort or saying where you are blocked. This is not the way this site works. I vote to close such a question.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\gcd(a-1,a^2+a+1)&=\gcd(a-1,a^2+a+1-(a+2)(a-1))\\
&=\gcd(a-1,3)\\
&=\begin{cases} 3 & \textrm{if }a\equiv 1\quad(\textrm{mod }3) \\ 1 & \textrm{if }a\not\equiv 1\quad(\textrm{mod }3) \end{cases}
\end{align}

The sum is $4$.

Comment: _Right, that's about it..._

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Let $a-1=b\iff a=?$

$$a^2+a+1=(b+1)^2+b+1+1=b^2+3b+3$$

$$(a-1,a^2+a+1)=(b,b^2+3b+3)=(b,3)$$